# Maximum of summed sin functions to keep values between -1 and +1

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In addition to the accepted answer down below, this is the result in C-esque pseudocode, for those who are using it for a similar purpose:

```
        sum = 0;

        for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
        {
            sum += 1d / k * sin(k * PI / (n + 1));
        }

        return sum;
```

**Original post down below:**

mathematics really is not my strong suit. I am a software developer and don't know the terminology, which is probably why I can't find an answer online on my own, apologies in advance.

I am working on a software oscillator at this moment. It consists of a set amount of sin functions, where the frequency of each is an integer multiple of the first. Sin #2 is 2x the frequency of sin #1, sin #N is Nx of sin #1 and so on.
The output of each is multiplied by 1/n to create a sawtooth shape, getting closer the more sin functions I add.

What I am struggling with is to find the relation between how many sin functions I have and the maximum value a single cycle would give me, as I need to fit the values within a range of -1 and +1.

As I need to sample in discrete time and process one step at a time, I can't wait to accumulate every possible value within a cycle to find out the maximum. How would I go about finding the maximum value based on how many sin functions are used?

Many thanks in advance, and apologies for the inconvenience!

This is a visualization of what I mean:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iwit0a4wzj

Comment: So basically, what you want to find is
$$
f(n) = \max_{x \in \mathbb R} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \sin (kx)
$$

Comment: Are all of the sine waves in phase or do you plan to change the phases? If there's no additional phase then this is trivial

Comment: Thanks, edited.

Comment: @StephenDonovan all waves are in phase. I do have the option to change phase, but it would affect all sin functions simultaneously, changing only when the cycle starts and ends for the entire graph.

Comment: Ok, my apologies but it's not as simple as I first thought, if all of the waves were cosines then it would be trivial because they'd always all constructively interfere at every $2\pi$. My apologies.

Comment: @MattiP. thank you for your time. My lack of knowledge makes it tough to figure out every piece of the equation, but it seems to be what I need. If I am not mistaken, this would sum the values of every sin function over every time step and extract the max from that result. Is it possible to figure out the maximum without brute-forcing over every sample step? I'm asking as I how no knowledge about previous or future timesteps in discrete time software

Comment: When I plot the functions (here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9mzhtjmm4u), it seems like the maximum of $g_n(x)=\sum \frac{1}{k}\sin(kx)$ always occurs at $x= \frac{\pi}{n+1}$. Therefore, while I am unable to prove it, it seems like the answer is
$$
\max_{x \in \mathbb R} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin (kx) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin \left( \frac{k\pi}{n+1} \right)
$$
While this is not easy to compute, at least it's a single expression.

Comment: @MattiP. typing your expression above into desmos with a slider for n seems to work flawlessly. As long as I can convert the expression into code, I should be fine. At least now I have a good starting point. Thank you very much! I had a feeling it was related to the position of each sin functions peaks but didn't know how to go about it. Goes to show that studying mathematics does pay off.

Comment: Also, the easy of computation is not too big of an issue in my case. This value will be computed once at the initialization of the oscillator, and (so long as I allow such feature) whenever n changes. By precomputing the value I can divide all samples by it, staying in range of -1 and +1. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @MattiP. Works perfectly. I would like to accept your answer as the solution, would you mind posting it again, but as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have some functions
$$
g_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin (kx)
$$
and you want to find the maximum of each of these, for every $n$. Skipping a few steps, the maximum of a given $g_n(x)$ is achieved at $x=\frac{\pi}{n+1}$, giving the result
$$
f(n) = \max_{x \in \mathbb R} g_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \sin \frac{k\pi}{n+1}
$$
This is a bit awkward expression to calculate, but at least it's a single line. The first few values of this "series" are the following:

- $n=1 \Rightarrow \max = 1$
- $n=2 \Rightarrow \max \approx 1.299~038$
- $n=3 \Rightarrow \max \approx 1.442~809$
- $n=4 \Rightarrow \max \approx 1.527~279$
- $n=5 \Rightarrow \max \approx 1.582~853$